# Can you create a fully custom entity in google Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a python telegram bot which I want to integrate with dialogflow. The python script outputs financial data for a given stock ticker. Can dialogflow recognize stock tickers? It does't show up in the built in entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom entities: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-custom.

I think you can recognize the stock tickers using regexp:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-regexp